# liferay: How to get a session variable from page type URL

Tags: session, liferay, liferay-6

I am keeping a value in session using hook, which I want to use when I am creating a page type URL as a parameter. Please help me in this.
Page types : http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/page+type

Answer (score 0):

With URL type page, users will leave the site and navigate to different site. The Servlet/Portlet Context will be different to that site and may not be able to access your Session variables. Please pass the variables in different way.